# CMake FetchContent: Compile in Debug and Release mode without source file duplication

Tags: c++, cmake

How can I use `FetchContent` in a way that source files are not duplicated, but binaries are still compiled once per build configuration (`Debug`, `Release`, etc.)?

When using `cmake`'s `FetchContent` with minimal options, e.g.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    <name>
    GIT_REPOSITORY <git_url>
    GIT_TAG <git_tag>
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(<name>)
```

a directory called `_deps` is created in the build directory, with three subdirs: `<name>-src`, `<name>-build` and `<name>-subbuild`. So both the source and binary files are written into a subdir of the build directory.

However, if several build directories exist, e.g. for `Debug` and `Release` builds, this is carried out for each, leading to unnecessary source file duplication. Also, all other libraries in my project are in `<source_root>/lib`, and the method of retrieval doesn't seem to be a good reason to split them up.
So I added

```
set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fetchContent)
```

inside the `CMakeLists.txt` in `<source_root>/lib`.
But now the binaries are only built once, with whichever flags happen to be used at that moment. So if I build everything in `Debug` mode first, and `Release` mode afterwards, I get a `Release` executable with libs that were built with `Debug` flags.

It seems like I'm missing something obvious here, since my case is hardly special. Maybe `FetchContent_Populate` is the way to go? But the `cmake` doc [advises against](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html?highlight=fetchcontent_declare#command:fetchcontent_populate) using it. Please advise.

Comment: Previously, it ignored half of the options that should be affected by `PREFIX`, as described for `ExternalProject_Add`.. I tried setting the prefix before, but I'll give this a shot.

Comment: A user named "Frank" recommended adding the `SOURCE_DIR` option to the `FetchContent_Declare` call. That is what my comment above was responding to.
His answer worked. Mostly. The download step was executed twice, overwriting the existing source files.

Comment: If you want sources for 3d-party project to be located **inside source directory** for your project, then instead of using `FetchContent` include that 3d-party project as a git submodule. If you want sources for 3d-party project to be located **outside** of your source directory, then the only possible place is build directory. In that case FetchContent is reasonable... but you cannot reuse the build directory of the Debug configuration for build the project in the Release configuration (and vice versa).

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but it adds another step to the setup procedure, i.e. not forgetting the `--recurse-submodules` flag everywhere. If I could configure my git project to automatically download submodules, without the user having to specify that, I might go that route. If that way appears in an answer, I'll accept it.